# A problem with polynomial root finding

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, crash, arbitrary-precision

I use the expression

```
N[(x - Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]*I + 10^-20*(1 + I))^50*(x - Sqrt[2] + 
     Sqrt[3]*I)^25*(x - Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]*I + 
     2*10^-20*(1 + I))^13*(x - Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]*I + 
     3*10^-20*(1 + I))^12, 5000]
```

to gernerate a highly ill-conditioned polynomial. Then I use

```
N[Expand[%, x], 5000]
```

to expand it. Finally, I want to use

```
NSolve[%, x, 50]
```

to solve it. However. the kernel breaks down after running thirty minutes or so, without indicating that it is out of memory.

Is this a *Mathematica* bug? Are there any bugs in the Jenkins Traub method?  Or are there bugs in *Mathematica*'s precision control?

Comment: That's an awful lot of precision.  Is it really necessary?

Comment: Does one really need to do `N[Expand[%, x], 5000]` since the expression is already set as `N[...., 5000]` ?? Would not a simple `Expand[%,x]` work just the same?

Comment: Wait, shouldn't first argument of `NSolve` be an equation or list of equations?

Comment: If you use `FindRoot`, you'll have better luck: `FindRoot[expr == 0, {x, 50}]` gives `{x -> 19.1982 - 1.09806 I}`  (but this ofcourse finds one root). But with a warning saying `Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision
within 100 iterations`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  No. If one write `NSolve[expr,x]` it will automatically do it as if one wrote `NSolve[expr==0,x]` see: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sf4O.png)  (this is on version 9)

Comment: When the expression is a polynomial, one can omit "==0" and just use the polynomial expression as the input parameters.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, I hadn't realized that.

Comment: It really needs so much digits.  Because when you want to solve the problem to 50 digits, the coefficients need to be 5000 digits long at least since it is a 100 degree polynomial.  Empirically speaking the bit-length of the polynomials depends linearly on the precision of the solution and the degree of the polynomials.  You can just think simply as follows.  Suppose the polynomial can be expressed as the (x-a1)*(x-a2)...(x-an), and a1, a2, ..., an  are all m digits long, then the last coefficients will be m*n digits long or so.

Comment: I believe Jenkins Traub method cannot apply to high degree polynomials that has cluster roots with high degrees.  Due to the convergence proof of the algorithm the method is somewhat like the power method in which the convergence rate depends on the ratio of the primary and second primary root in modulus.  In addition, it linearly convergence rate and the small cubical convergence basin makes it hard to solve the problems like the example or even those with high density of simple roots.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, I tried all the versions from 5.0-9.0 on windows 7 x64 and it remains the crash.  It is acceptable that the problem cannot be solved due to the algorithm itself, but the screen shot is not friendly and wolfram do not give any recommendation.  Users may think if there are any dangerous factors in the functions that mathematica provided.  Hope it can be reported as an issue.

Comment: You can report this problem yourself by sending email to support@wolfram.com, including self contained code that produces the problem, with screen shot if possible, and your system information.

Comment: It is an ntdll.dll crash.

Comment: @Zhong if in Linux try building MPSolve which can be found http://poisson.phc.unipi.it/~robol/trac/. And if there is some cross platform C wizard among us probably building it in Windows is also possible http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/wstein/www/home/jason/mpsolve-3.1.3/configure.ac

Answer (score 6):

The crash is because you set `WorkingPrecision` too low.

Simply making WorkingPrecision higher solved the problem. (no crash) but notice that some roots print saying `no significant digits available to display` (pink boxes).

I found this when I increased the `WorkingPrecision` to 5000 from 50, and then saw the message `NSolve::precw: The precision of the argument function....is less than WorkingPrecision`  (but no crash!, strange)

So, I just put it at Infinity, which is default, from looking at options:

```
Select[Flatten[
  Trace[NSolve[expr == 0, x], TraceInternal -> True]], ! 
   FreeQ[#, Method | NSolve`MethodData] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr = N[(x - Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] I + 10^-20 (1 + I))^50*(x - Sqrt[2] + 
       Sqrt[3] I)^25 (x - Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]*I + 
       2*10^-20*(1 + I))^13*(x - Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]*I + 
       3*10^-20*(1 + I))^12, 5000];
expr = N[Expand[expr, x], 5000];
NSolve[expr == 0, x, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Exactly when I tried to rationalize the expression, then the answers seems right.  It is suggested to rationalize the expression when dealing with such steep polynomials.